# Test significance of events within AR model

Tags: regression, statistical-significance

I am new to this forum and was hoping I could get some help.

I have a piece of time-series data collated over the space of 3 years, and this has been fit to an AR model (I believe an 'ARIMA' model is available also). Within this period of time, there have been policy changes, which, in theory, should affect the line. How do I test whether each policy change is significant?

Thank you for advice you give.

Answer (score 0):

if you knew when they occurred it is possible to estimate their effect. Alternatively these effects can often be detected in the data suggesting a time period (de facto) different from the known (de jure) time period suggesting either a delay or an anticipation factor. If you wish to post your data I will try and help further.

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your response. I am in the process of building my dataset, so cannot give it to you completed, but I have a set of events for 2017, with values of volatility before and after the event. I want to test if ultimately, the events are significant upon the index. Is this something you would be able to help with? Thank you.

Comment: possibly.. i would have to see your data matrix ... please provide a csv file